# Efficiently compute 2D histogram with Pyspark (Numpy and UDF)

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, user-defined-functions, histogram2d

I'm trying to do something really simple which somehow translates into something really difficult when Pyspark is involved.

I have a really large dataframe (~2B rows) on our platform which I'm not allowed to download but only analyse using Pyspark code. The dataframe contains position of some objects over Europe in the last year and I want to compute the density of those objects over time. I've succesfully used the function `numpy.histogram2d` in the past with good results (it's the faster that I've found in `numpy` at least). Since there is no equivalent of this function in `pyspark` I've defined a UDF to compute the density and return a new dataframe. This works when I only process a few rows (I've tried with 100K rows):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def compute_density(df):
    lon_bins = np.linspace(-15, 45, 100)
    lat_bins = np.linspace(35, 70, 100)

    density, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(df["corrected_latitude_degree"].values,
                                             df["corrected_longitude_degree"].values,
                                             [lat_bins, lon_bins])
    x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])
    x_out = x2d.ravel()
    y_out = y2d.ravel()
    density_out = density.ravel()
    data = {
            'latitude': x_out,
            'longitude': y_out,
            'density': density_out
            }
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which I then call as this

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType()),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType()),
    StructField("density", DoubleType())
])

preproc = (
    inp
    .limit(100000)
    .withColumn("groups", F.lit(0))
)
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def compute_density_udf(df):
    return compute_density(df)

result = preproc.groupby(["groups"]).apply(compute_density_udf)
```

Why am I using the `GROUPED_MAP` version to apply the UDF? I didn't manage to get it work with the `SCALAR` type UDF when returning with a schema, although I don't really need to group.

When I try to use this UDF on the full dataset I get an OOM, cause I believe there is only one group and is too much for the UDF to process. I'm sure there is a smarter way to compute this directly with `pyspark` without an UDF or alternatively split into groups and then assemble the results at the end? Does anyone have any idea/suggestion?

Comment: Did you manage to find something for this in the end?

Comment: Nope. Got no suggestions